# goconvey not showing coverage of packages

Tags: goconvey

In goconvey, there's a feature that shows package coverage, and when you click on the package under analysis, the go coverage tool pops up, showing the source code, colored by what has and hasn't been covered.

For example: [image]

[image]

However, there are many packages in my SUT that, when clicked on, **don't** show any test coverage, and even 404. For example, clicking on package db from that list:

[image]

Another example: [image]

What is causing this and how do I remedy it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it applies to this case but for me in Mac I had to run the goconvey tool in sudo mode (i.e Admin in Windows). Otherwise the intermediate files/dirs creation failed with the tool/webserver reporting 'no coverage'.

Since you are receiving 404, did you validate if the coverage report dir/files were created?